# Laravel npm run dev shared hosting

Tags: laravel

I upload my latavel project into a multi site shares hosting with multi website

/home/servername/domaine1.com
/..../........./domaine.com
...

Laravel project in question lead in directory domaine1.com

I edit my .even file with database credentials I change the server link I moved index.php to domaine1.com directory I cleaned bootstrap cache when I run the app i have this message

**npm run dev no manifest ...**

I tried npm on server but not recognized
I tried also npm run build them override the public on server still nothing

Any ideas